# TempDirectory extension: is there a replacement for createInCustomDirectory() methods?

Tags: junit5, junit5-extension-model

There used to be `createInCustomDirectory()` methods in TempDirectory extension class in JUnit 5.4.0-M1 (see [docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.0-M1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/support/io/TempDirectory.html)). The main use case for those methods was to change tmp dir used by the extension. In the final release (5.4.0) TempDirectory extension was made private and enabled by default and those methods are not available anymore.

I wonder if there is another way to change root dir for all `@TempDir` directories?

Comment: An update for those who are interested in a workaround. You can override system property for temp dir when running tests in the following manner: `-Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp`. As JUnit internally uses `java.nio.file.Files#createTempDirectory` internally, it'll do the trick.

Comment: Very nice workaround!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to customize the temp dir.

The scope of the `@TempDir` was reduced in JUnit 5.4 RC2. See the following issue for details: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1752